# iPhone Reminders how to determine account

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders

How do I see which account my lists belongs to in the Reminders app? I'm using an iPhone with iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

When you open the reminders app, it will either show a display of all the lists or show you the items in one list.

If you are in the detailed view, tap the white area at the bottom of the screen to bring up the List View.

Each list that is synced through a cloud service has that service listed in grey to the right of the item count. Those without text are stored on the device only.